# Is there any way to clone a policy from a tenant to another tenant in Azure ADB2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to clone a custom policy from an ADB2C tenant to another one uploading the XML file through the "identity experience framework" interface
but I get the following error:

```
Unable to upload policy. Reason : Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_B2C_1_SIGNUPIN" of tenant "tenant.onmicrosoft.com".Policy 'B2C_1A_B2C_1_SignUpIn' of tenant 'tenat.onmicrosoft.com' is not allowed to inherit from the specified base policy. Inheritance chain: {
 "TenantId": "tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
 "PolicyId": "base-v1",
 "TenantObjectId": "xxxx...",
 "Root": true,
 "Derived": {
 "TenantId": "tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
 "PolicyId": "B2C_1A_B2C_1_SignUpIn",
 "TenantObjectId": "yyyy...",
 "Rule": "All",
 "InheritanceAllowed": false,
 "Reason": "Policy 'B2C_1A_B2C_1_SignUpIn' in tenant 'yyyyy...' is blocked from inheriting policies from 'xxxx...' as the basic policy constraint handler 'B2CBasicPoliciesOnly' cannot match the policy id to a prefix or registered policy id."
 }
 }
```

This is the policy content:

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="tenant.onmicrosoft.com" TenantObjectId="xxx...." 
  PolicyId="B2C_1_SignUpIn" PublicPolicyUri="http://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>tenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>base-v1</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="displayName">
        <DisplayName>Username</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <Restriction MergeBehavior="Append" />
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="givenName">
        <DisplayName>First Name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <Restriction MergeBehavior="Append" />
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="surname">
        <DisplayName>Last name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <Restriction MergeBehavior="Append" />
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="extension_Service">
        <DisplayName>Service Name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <Restriction MergeBehavior="Append" />
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-Common">
          <EnabledForUserJourneys>OnClaimsExistence</EnabledForUserJourneys>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
            <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
            <Item Key="refresh_token_lifetime_secs">1209600</Item>
            <Item Key="rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs">7776000</Item>
            <Item Key="IssuanceClaimPattern">AuthorityAndTenantGuid</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationContextReferenceClaimPattern">None</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Input">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Organization" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Department" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Service" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Organization" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Department" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Service" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadCommon">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Organization" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Department" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Service" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-WriteCommon">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Organization" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Department" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Service" />
          </PersistedClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signinandsignupwithpassword">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="B2CSignUpOrSignInWithPassword" />
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" />
      <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
      <SessionExpiryInSeconds>86400</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Organization" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Service" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Department" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="trustFrameworkPolicy" Required="true" DefaultValue="{policy}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Downloading standard policies and then uploading them (whether with or without modification) is not supported.**

Looks like thats what you tried which makes your standard policy a custom policy. Custom policies cannot have base-v1 in the inheritance hierarchy. The base-v1 policies are strictly meant to be used by the standard policies.

The error indicates that your (now) custom policy is inheriting from base-v1.

Comment: That's correct, I've tried downloading a standard policy to clone it to another tenant. So is it definitely not possible (even if you don't modify them) ?

Comment: It's not as simple as just uploading the policies. The tenant state could be different (e.g. which extension attributes exist in that tenant), and tenant-wide B2C options can vary too (e.g. which IDPs are configured, what are the client_ids for social IDPs, etc.). What if conflicting policies are being uploaded, e.g. one that relies on usernames, another that relies on email addresses, and so on. The list of challenges to overcome is endless. So any time a policy is downloaded, it is treated as a custom policy after that.

Comment: alas, that translates in the need to manually set up every configuration setting for each ADB2C instance (ie. production vs developement environment) which goes far against the "infrastructure as code" principle

Comment: This is an area currently being invested in. I understand that a programmatic way of creating and editing policies is expected to be provided.