# Cannot Import an Azure B2C User Flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a B2C Userflow that I have downloaded. After doing a few minor changes I want to upload this as a Custom User Flow (via IEF).

When I do this I get the following error.

[image: Upload Custom Policy Error]

Is there some way to upload this without getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check by uploading modified built-in userflow:

But received the  error: `Policy 'B2C_1A_B2C_1_signinup' of tenant 'xxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com' is not allowed to inherit from the specified base policy.`

[image]

Then modified  the policyId and tried to upload but received the same error

```
Upload custom policy

Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_B2C_1_SIGNINUP" of tenant "kxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com".Policy 'B2C_1A_B2C_1_signinup' of tenant 'kxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com' is not allowed to inherit from the specified base policy. Inheritance chain: {
  "TenantId": "kavyaxxxub2c.onmicrosoft.com",
  "PolicyId": "base-v1",
  "TenantObjectId": "xxxx",
  "Root": true,
  "Derived": {
    "TenantId": "kxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
    "PolicyId": "B2C_1A_B2C_1_signinup",
    "TenantObjectId": "xxxx",
    "Rule": "All",
    "InheritanceAllowed": false,
    "Reason": "Policy 'B2C_1A_B2C_1_signinup' in tenant '376b389fxxxxxe68' is blocked from inheriting policies from 'xxxx83xxxxx' as the basic policy constraint handler 'B2CBasicPoliciesOnly' cannot match the policy id to a prefix or registered policy id."
  }
}
```

Note: ***Downloading the built-in policy or userflow, modifying it  and then uploading it is not  supported.***

supporting reference:  [Is there any way to clone a policy | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570877/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-policy-from-a-tenant-to-another-tenant-in-azure-adb2)

If you are wanting to customize the sign-in flow, then you must use a custom policy.

Refer : [Can't upload policy · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/5303)

Comment: That Download button only adds to a developer's confusion and frustration. Why do they even have that?